# What is the usage of OJDBC14.jar

Tags: ojdbc

What is usage of OJDBC14.jar... I tried to search at google but no thread for the same. Well, after looking into the jar I think this is the ORACLE-DataBase implementation of the JDBC interfaces. i.e vendor specific JDBC implementation

Comment: ok. So who provides the implementation of JDBC interfaces and where are they stored? I mean in which JAR file or component?

Comment: Implementation is provided by Oracle and *stored* inside `OJDBC14.jar`. This is vendor specific implementation: Vendor is Oracle. JDBC is Specification.